# External VCC for USB cable while keeping data connection

Tags: arduino, power-supply, usb, vcc

I want to connect my android phone and arduino to create a fast and reliable serial connection. I've read that it is possible with USB OTG but i will need to charge my phone eventually. So i was wondering if i can use another USB cable to feed VCC for both cables while maintaining data connection between arduino and android. I created this simple schematic. Will this work for what i wanted to do? (Sorry for mistakes. English is not my native language.)

[image: External VCC for 2 USB Cables]

Thanks

Comment: Who is USB master and who is USB slave in your schematics? Also, modern smartphones have micro-B connectors, which have extra ID pin. Where is it in your schematics?

Comment: @Ale..chenski android will be the master and arduino will be the slave. I planned this as a board where i can connect 3 usb cables this is why i added 3 USB-A connectors. In this case do i need id pin?

Comment: ID Pin is used with OTG to determine who will be host side of USB and who will be device side of USB. You should read up about this from numerous web pages. As long as the Android phone is in host side role most phones cannot be charged as the host side is supplying the USB V+.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Now i'm on right path. I knew it can't be this easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this won't work. You need to make or buy so-called "accessory charger adapter", or "ACA". Here is the [correct arrangement](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/otg-charging-using-usb-aca-accessory-t3431856):

[image]

It might be though that your smartphone doesn't support this ACA arrangement, this method is old.